# Encoded password does not look like BCrypt and question about Roles

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-security

I have two questions I can't find any info about.

1. There are my two methods I call to save user with encoded password in DB.
   If I call register() from Controller password is not being encoded. And I have warning message "Encoded password does not look like BCrypt".

Why is it so? ( I am sure it's connected only with code below ).

I know how silly my questions may sound, I do appreciate your answers a lot.

```
@Override
public User register(String username, String password, String firstName, String lastName, String email) {

    if (userRepository.findByUsername(username).isEmpty()) {
        User user = new User(username,password,firstName,lastName,email);
        user.grantRole(UserRole.ROLE_USER);
        userRepository.save(user);
        return user;

    } else {
        throw new NoSuchUserException();
    }



   }
 @Override
    public void save(User user) {
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        user.setRoles(new HashSet<>(roleRepository.findAll()));
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
```

2. What does this code do? I am already setting a Role in register(). findAll() method just returns all entities from a table. So the code adds all Roles from table to user? Why would people need it?

   user.setRoles(new HashSet<>(roleRepository.findAll()));

I know how silly my questions may sound, I do appreciate your answers a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In order to solve the problem: `"Encoded password does not look like BCrypt"`. Make sure the length of the “password” column is at least 60.
- Line `user.setRoles(new HashSet<>(roleRepository.findAll()));` will pull all roles from database and set distinct values to current user. This line is ok if you want to create an admin user if you want to create another user you need to find a subset of the roles.